# how to verify the MimeEntity of dncrypted,and the signed fomart using “”application/pkcs7-mime

Tags: c#, .net, mimekit

When I decrypting the signed and encrypted messages ,I successfully decrypt and get a "MimeEntity", his smime-type is "signed-data".

but the signature format is not "multipart/signed", and the format is "application/pkcs7-mime".

I convert it to "ApplicationPkcs7Mime", "multipart", "textpart", "messagepart", but I get "null" value.

But I can normally open this message in outlook,I use outlook to send this message , the content is not "mimikit" generated.

I will only convert  "message.body" to "ApplicationPkcs7Mime", but about the "decrypted MimeEntity" how should I do?

code:

```
var parser = new MimeParser(new MemoryStream(content), MimeFormat.Default);

   MimeMessage  message = parser.ParseMessage();



        if (message.Body is  ApplicationPkcs7Mime) {

            using (var ctx = new MySecureMimeContext()) {  

                var encrypted = message.Body as ApplicationPkcs7Mime;

                if (encrypted != null && encrypted.SecureMimeType == SecureMimeType.EnvelopedData){

                    ctx.Import(new MemoryStream(p12data.blob),p12data.Pwd);

                    MimeEntity decrypted = encrypted.Decrypt(ctx);

                    if (decrypted is MultipartSigned) {                          
                        var signed = (MultipartSigned)decrypted;
                        var protocol = signed.ContentType.Parameters["protocol"];
                        if (ctx.Supports(protocol)){
                            if (signed[0] is TextPart && signed[1] is ApplicationPkcs7Signature) {
                                var extracted = (TextPart)signed[0];
                                var signatures = signed.Verify(ctx);

                                if (signatures != null && signatures.Count > 0) {
                                    foreach (var signature in signatures){
                                        bool valid = signature.Verify();
                                        if (!valid){
                                            isverify = false;
                                            return isverify;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        string signType = decrypted.ContentType.Parameters["smime-type"];                
                        if (signType == "signed-data"){    
                            //what can 1 do?
                            var signed = message.Body as ApplicationPkcs7Mime;
                        }                           
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
else {
    string signType = decrypted.ContentType.Parameters["smime-type"];                
    if (signType == "signed-data"){    
        //what can 1 do?
        var signed = message.Body as ApplicationPkcs7Mime;
    }                           
}
```

with:

```
else if (decrypted is ApplicationPkcs7Mime) {
    var signed = (ApplicationPkcs7Mime) decrypted;
    if (signed.SecureMimeType == SecureMimeType.SignedData) {
        // extract the original content and get a list of signatures
        MimeEntity original;

        // Note: if you are rendering the message, you'll want to render the
        // original mime part rather than the application/pkcs7-mime part.
        foreach (var signature in pkcs7.Verify (out original)) {
            try {
                bool valid = signature.Verify ();

                // If valid is true, then it signifies that the signed content
                // has not been modified since this particular signer signed the
                // content.
                // 
                // However, if it is false, then it indicates that the signed
                // content has been modified.
            } catch (DigitalSignatureVerifyException) {
                // There was an error verifying the signature.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I just copy/pasted this code snippet from http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/WorkingWithSMime.htm